# SQL Server Import Data - Set column as Long Text

Tags: sql-server

I have been constantly trying to get the SQL Server import to be handle longer then 255 characters.  Sometimes, it appears as Long text and sometimes it appears as varchar(255).  Is there a way to change it to nvarchar(max).

What I have been doing is adding spaces to the top row of the excel as a workaround.

I was looking for a better solution

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find better solution then padding field with blanks.

When importing and I see a field that is varchar(255). I click Edit Sql and then change the sql for the create table sql to have the fields set to max or whatever is needed. Then Change the size of the destination

**Edit SQL**

[image]

**Column Mappings**

[image]